# How can I subtract this face from another one?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I have a model like this:

[image: Base model]

I addet a plane, resized it, and created circles at two corners using SHIFT+A. Now, I want to remove the faces from the circles from the face of the rectangle. Also I want to delete these two circles later. How can I do this? Please note that I'm a Blender beginner :)

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join all the shapes if it's not already the case (select the objects and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join), select the circle and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)* and in the *Operator* box (at the bottom left of the 3D view once you've booleaned) choose *Boolean Operation > Union* and *Solver > Exact* :

[image]

Then you can remove the circle. Or, as John Eason suggests, use the *Knife Project* tool.

Comment: I am using Blender 2.79 because of DirectX compatability; when I click Intersect (Boolean) it creates some weird looking shapes and if I delete the circle, it deletes the rectangle too. https://imgur.com/a/nK3yXTi

Comment: In that case, look for a tutorial on the Boolean Modifier for your Blender version. On reflection, you could also use the Knife Project tool assuming it was available in those days.

Comment: I trust you that this is working in Blender 3 so I will accept that :)

Comment: Yes Kinfe Project works in 2.79, the shortcuts are not the same as in 3 though, see this tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0lA9iJxnlM